# Error in Controller for dotNet VUser while VUgen is working fine

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

My dotnet virtual user script is working fine on VUGen but not able to run on controller( on same machine so no conflict of .Net version etc.).

**Error**: Failed to compile virtual user.
**Error**: Action.cs(29,35): error CS0103: The name 'DLLtoLR' does not exist in the current context
**Error**: Action.cs(16,12): error CS0103: The name 'strOutputMsg' does not exist in the current context
**Error**: Action.cs(16,27): error CS0103: The name 'Class1' does not exist in the current context

I went through with [the following link](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/LoadRunner-Support-Forum/error-failed-to-compile-virtual-user/td-p/6215877#.VRvhtfnF9VI) but with no avail.

**N.B.** I am using my dlls.

Comment: Could you check if your dlls are being copied to the LG? In Controller, right click on the gray rectangle to the left of the script name. Select Details from the popup menu. In the dialog, select More from the right side panel. In the opened tabs below select Files tab and see that your dlls are there.

Comment: Adding one more link if people need to troubleshoot more:http://easyloadrunner.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/how-to-set-systems-temp-and-tmp.html

Comment: Thanks Buzzy, No Dlls was not there, I manually added now into them. But still same errors.

Comment: The error has been resolved after adding dlls as Buzzy suggested

Comment: I think you need to add the dlls from Visual Studio as references. You cannot add references from VuGen (as far as I can remember)

Comment: yes That is the case

Comment: OK, I will add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that some of the dlls required to run the script on the controller are not in the references of the .NET project and hence are not copied to the LG.

To add the references open the project in Visual Studio and add the references to the project. Currently there is no way to add the references directly from VuGen.